# Missing Python Packaging Tools on Python Interpreter - Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, pycharm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been working on a basic Django project and I deployed it to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I'm not sure if that's causing this, but I'm just telling you this so that you know what I might have been done with my project. Then, my python project interpreter got kinda messy and when I try to run the application it started to give me some errors about missing packages. After that, I checked my project interpreter, and it was like this:

[image: image 1]

Then, I tried to install the required packages using PyCharm, however, it kept giving me the error below. I also tried to build some of those packages manually, like Django, on my own terminal but the error was same. Further, I was able to install packages on other python versions on my mac, which sorta tells I might have messed my default python interpreter somehow.

[image]

> 40:357: execution error: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/var/folders/f1/k7c234sx5fn9j84yt130_znr0000gn/T/tmp2zDEZTpycharm-management/pip-9.0.1/setup.py",
>   line 6, in 
>       from setuptools import setup, find_packages   File "/Users/bkaankuguoglu/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/setuptools/**init**.py",
>   line 12, in 
>       import setuptools.version   File "/Users/bkaankuguoglu/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/setuptools/version.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       import pkg_resources   File "/Users/bkaankuguoglu/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 72, in 
>       import packaging.requirements   File "/Users/bkaankuguoglu/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/packaging/requirements.py",
>   line 59, in 
>       MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR())("marker") TypeError: **call**() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)  (1)

I'd really appreciate any help here and please ask me if any extra detail is needed to answer this question before downvoting.

Comment: In your `MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR())("marker")`. Is there a mistake there. It seems you are passing only one argument instead of two. @bkaankuguoglu

Comment: But the thing is, that's not part of my code. It just tries to install some required packaging tools and encounters an error.

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install setuptools==33.1.1
```